# Is it a bad practice to use version managers like RVM inside docker containers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rvm, dockerfile

I'm new to using docker and so far I'm unable to find many ruby/rails images that contain `RVM` or `rbenv`.

The most common thing I see is that each **container** has multiple **tags** and each tagged image version has **only one** version of Ruby installed. See this [image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) for example.

The only way to use another version is to use another tag for the image you are using as you can not install a new version with RVM nor with rbenv.

Is this done on purpose?

Is it a bad practice to use version managers for programming languages inside docker containers?

Why?

Comment: Why do you want to run several versions of Ruby in one container? Or why do you want to switch the configuration of a container without re-building?

Comment: @spickermann As I said I'm new to Docker. It seems kind of odd to me that you have to update the entire image to use a different ruby version.

Comment: I don't have much experience working with docker too, but afaik one of the reasons to use docker it to have a reproducible configuration of a server or service as code. Once you change the configuration of a docker container at runtime, another person will not be able to build the exact same build without talking to you about the changes you made. From that point of view it makes perfectly sense to me, not to use multiple versions of Ruby in one container, but to pin the configuration to one specific version.

Comment: DO NOT VOTE DOWN, this is a great questions for guys who sticks with RVM no matter what. Answer bellow is a perfect explanation for that, at least some prove for such legacy lovers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be considered a bad practice or anti-pattern in docker. RVM is trying to solve a similar problem that docker is solving, but with a very different approach. RVM is designed for a host or VM with all the tools installed in one place. Docker creates an isolated environment where only the tools you need to run your single application are included.

Containers are ideally minimalistic, only containing the prerequisites needed for your application, making them more portable. Docker also uses layers and a union filesystem to reuse common base images for each image, so any copy of something like Ruby version X is only downloaded and written to disk once, ever (ignoring updates to that image).

Comment: Great explanation. It's good to know how the two tools relate to each other.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are going to use it. If you need to install about any version of ruby on the custom docker image without messing around with downloading tarballs and applying patches RVM can be just perfect. RVM is basically a bash script so using it inside of docker container is as bad as using any other bash script inside of docker container.