Ruby environment in Dockerfile using RVM - FROM Ubuntu
In my small Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:24.04
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN apt update
RUN apt update && apt install -y gnupg2 curl software-properties-common build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf automake libtool bison libffi-dev
RUN gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
RUN \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io -o rvm.sh
# RUN cat rvm.sh | bash -s stable --rails -- installs ruby with rvm
RUN bash rvm.sh stable
RUN bash -l -c "rvm install 3.0.0"


I'm trying to install Ruby using RVM and I'm getting this error. It suggests to look at .log files but i dont seem to get any valuable info from that.
RVM is succesfully downloaded and installed and when i run container I easily install Ruby, but from Dockerfile I'm struggling.
I also tried putting source source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm which didn't work so i did . ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm which worked but still couldnt install ruby from Dockerfile.

ruby with rvm
   8 |     RUN bash rvm.sh stable
   9 | >>> RUN bash -l -c "rvm install 3.0.0 --disable-binary --trace"
  10 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -c bash -l -c \"rvm install 3.0.0 --disable-binary --trace\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2


Is there a particular reason you would want to install rvm in docker rather than just using the official ruby 3.0 docker image? I cannot think of a reason why one would need a version manager in a container when you can just manage 1 version per container.

@engineersmnky its for an internship task :)

Still doesn't really answer the question but maybe one of these can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77894057/1978251, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62822197/1978251. This is also worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41925488/1978251

@engineersmnky The task says to make a Dockerfile with multiple ruby versions installed using RVM. I must build and run the Ruby project in CI on GitHub in that docker container. I guess the multiple-version compatibility is the goal.

@OgnjenGligoric A Docker container runs a single process, and a typical image has only a single program installed in it that can be the main container process.  When would a single process need multiple Ruby versions at the same time?
